# IndexedDB - Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements

Tags: javascript, json, indexeddb

I am trying to store data into an IndexedDB, but I am encountering a problem. When trying to add the well formatted JSON data I get the error:

```
DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements.
```

Below is my IndexedDB code:

```
function dbInit(key, value) {
    // Open (or create) the database
    var open = indexedDB.open("MyDatabase", 6);

    // Create the schema
    open.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        var db = open.result;
        var store = db.createObjectStore("MyObjectStore", {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
        var index = store.createIndex("types", "types");
    };

    open.onsuccess = function() {
        // Start a new transaction
        var db = open.result;
        var tx = db.transaction("MyObjectStore", "readwrite");
        var store = tx.objectStore("MyObjectStore");
        var index = store.index("types");


        // Add some data
        store.put(value);


        // Close the db when the transaction is done
        tx.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        };
    }
}
```

After looking through some similar questions I have noticed that this issue is present if a keyPath is not specified, but below I have specified the keyPath to "id" and autoIncrement: true so this should act as the keyPath.

Below is the JSON data that I am trying to add - Passed into function under 'value' paramater. (Modified data as it is sensetitive, but in this format.)

```
[{
    "code": 1,
    "content": "XXX.html",
    "scheme": 4,
    "type": "XXX"
}, {
    "code": 2,
    "content": "XXX.html",
    "scheme": 6,
    "type": "XXX"
}, {
    "code": 3,
    "content": "XXX.html",
    "scheme": 1,
    "type": "XXX"
}, {
    "code": 4,
    "content": "XXX.html",
    "scheme": 4,
    "type": "XXX"
}]
```

Comment: I don't see any troubles. [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4o2obfe0/1/). I've used your function and [there's](https://imgur.com/a/E3QWS) screenshot of the result (You can see yourself at Chrome DevTools Application tab). Also check your JSON, there's `}` at the end instead of `]`

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps this is a Firefox issue? I am getting this error every time, and unfortunately, this is a Firefox application and won't run on Chrome. Just noticed the } at the end of the JSON, this was just a typo when editing the JSON for Stack Overflow and is a ] in the live code.

Comment: Hm, firefox without any plugins [got me the same result](https://imgur.com/a/EGmKz) (OS: Windows 10).

Comment: That is odd. Also on Windows 10 with no plugins. It must be something to do with the way I am passing the data into the function. I'll keep searching!

Comment: Did you parse your JSON? I've got your error when i tried to pass JSON string to function instead of JSON object or array.

Comment: Doesn't like me Parsing the data as its already well formated JSON, get an error if I try to parse that data.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the value in as a string or parsed into an Array?

If a string, then the problem is that the generated key (c/o `autoIncrement: true`) can't be assigned to the value (c/o `keyPath: "id"`) since you can't add properties to strings.

Simpler repro:

```
indexedDB.open('k').onupgradeneeded = e => {
  const db = e.target.result;
  const s = db.createObjectStore('s', {keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true}); 
  s.put('string');
};
```